# instead of the username django value, I get "<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000017E365030D0>" (i see in SQLiteStudio)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I wanted to create a user without entering username and password, but only first_name, last_name and phone_number and so that username when creating a user was equal to phone_number

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                    help_text="Введите номер телефона пользователя",
                                    verbose_name="Номер телефона")

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = User.phone_number
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from users.models import User


class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['image']


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=100)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='phone_number', max_length=11)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'phone_number')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.phone_number
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .forms import UserCreateForm
from .models import *


@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    list_display = ('last_name', 'phone_number', 'is_staff')
    list_display_links = ('last_name', 'phone_number')
    search_fields = ('last_name', 'phone_number')
    ordering = ['last_name']
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ("wide",),
                "fields": ("username", 'phone_number'),
            },
        ),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (_("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", 'image')}),
        (
            _("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
```

Googled that problem and didn't find a similar one. For others, this problem was related to view.py , where they tried to create a user, but I create it in the admin.py

P.S.
(On the main page of the site, I'm trying to log in to my profile using phone_number and I can only log in using one profile, I can't explain why, but only one works, although the others also issue such a request in username.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `self`, so:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        help_text="Введите номер телефона пользователя",
        verbose_name="Номер телефона",
    )

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.phone_number
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name
```

but overriding the `save` method is *not* very safe, since a lot of (bulk) database updates circumvent the `.save()` method.